# Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks): MacOSX10.6.sdk deprecation

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk, osx-mavericks

I have been working on a project which has some significant dependency on OS X 10.6's sdk. Now, when I build the application on OS X mavericks using `Xcode 4.6`, it cannot find the above mentioned sdk.

Is the `MacOSX10.6.sdk` deprecated on OS X mavericks?

If yes, then is there any workaround or do I need to go through the dreaded path of finding solutions to all the problems that have surfaced by not choosing the base sdk as 10.6?

Comment: It's got more to do with Xcode's support for an SDK, not the version of OSX. What's wrong with building with the latest SDK?

Comment: Yes. And earlier versions of Xcode are not supported on 10.9. What I see is that I am heading towards the direction which I am trying to avoid. The latest SDK might have deprecated some of the previously supported APIs.

Comment: Yes, it will have done, and that's a good thing as you get insight into that during development, not during customer-use.  For deprecated APIs you have to provide multiple code-paths through your code, depending on the OSX-version, which is determined at runtime.

Comment: No, deprecated APIs don't mean that you have to provide multiple code paths, unless you are planning to sell through the App Store.  Deprecated APIs are still available, but may be removed in a later SDK.